# joining two tables using entity Framework core and asp.net core webapi

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have two tables by name formcontrols and otherfields both table has one common column by name FormId
The basic understanding is a from can have multiple formcontrols and multiple otherfields with same formID

Below is the screenshort for formcontrols table

[image]

Below is the screenshort for otherfields table

[image]

As we can see from above two tables we have common FormID as 10

i need to write a linq query to get all this data in one request
i tried doing it but i am getting duplicate otherfield object on each loop
below is my code

```cs
 var formControls = await 
 (
    from d in _context.FormControls 
    join f in _context.OtherFields on d.FormId equals f.FormID 
    where d.FormId == request.FormId 
    select new FormControlsDto
    {
        FormControls = d,
        OtherFields = f
    }
 ).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

The Json Response which i am getting is

```json
[
  {
    "formControls": {
      "formId": 10,
      "controlName": "code",
      "fieldName": "code",
      "icon": null,
      "arbCaption": "code",
      "engCaption": "code",
      "maxLength": "",
      "minLength": "",
      "maxValue": "",
      "minValue": "",
      "dataType": "text",
      "isHidden": false,
      "defaultValue": "",
      "defaultValueScalarFun": "",
      "required": true,
      "regExpression": "",
      "controlType": "textbox",
      "searchId": 0,
      "anotherCriteria": "",
      "disabled": false,
      "indexPage": true,
      "width": 0,
      "section": 1,
      "autoGenerate": false,
      "rank": 0,
      "engToolTip": "FirstName",
      "arbToolTip": "FirstName",
      "id": 1,
      "createdDate": "2023-01-29T09:40:24.0446711",
      "updatedDate": "2023-01-29T09:40:24.0446711",
      "modifyUserId": 0,
      "regUserId": 0
    },
    "otherFields": {
      "formID": 10,
      "width": 0,
      "rank": 3,
      "isHidden": false,
      "engName": "Cost",
      "arbName": "Cost",
      "fieldType": "textbox",
      "dataType": "text",
      "dataLength": 0,
      "remarks": null,
      "isFilter": true,
      "isInList": true,
      "modifyDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "id": 4,
      "createdDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "updatedDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "modifyUserId": 0,
      "regUserId": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "formControls": {
      "formId": 10,
      "controlName": "EngName",
      "fieldName": "EngName",
      "icon": null,
      "arbCaption": "EngName",
      "engCaption": "EngName",
      "maxLength": null,
      "minLength": null,
      "maxValue": null,
      "minValue": null,
      "dataType": "text",
      "isHidden": false,
      "defaultValue": null,
      "defaultValueScalarFun": null,
      "required": true,
      "regExpression": null,
      "controlType": "textbox",
      "searchId": 0,
      "anotherCriteria": null,
      "disabled": false,
      "indexPage": true,
      "width": 0,
      "section": 1,
      "autoGenerate": false,
      "rank": 1,
      "engToolTip": "EngName",
      "arbToolTip": "EngName",
      "id": 6,
      "createdDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "updatedDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "modifyUserId": 0,
      "regUserId": 0
    },
    "otherFields": {
      "formID": 10,
      "width": 0,
      "rank": 3,
      "isHidden": false,
      "engName": "Cost",
      "arbName": "Cost",
      "fieldType": "textbox",
      "dataType": "text",
      "dataLength": 0,
      "remarks": null,
      "isFilter": true,
      "isInList": true,
      "modifyDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "id": 4,
      "createdDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "updatedDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "modifyUserId": 0,
      "regUserId": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "formControls": {
      "formId": 10,
      "controlName": "ArbName",
      "fieldName": "ArbName",
      "icon": null,
      "arbCaption": "ArbName",
      "engCaption": "ArbName",
      "maxLength": null,
      "minLength": null,
      "maxValue": null,
      "minValue": null,
      "dataType": "text",
      "isHidden": false,
      "defaultValue": null,
      "defaultValueScalarFun": null,
      "required": true,
      "regExpression": null,
      "controlType": "textbox",
      "searchId": 0,
      "anotherCriteria": null,
      "disabled": false,
      "indexPage": true,
      "width": 0,
      "section": 1,
      "autoGenerate": false,
      "rank": 2,
      "engToolTip": "ArbName",
      "arbToolTip": "ArbName",
      "id": 7,
      "createdDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "updatedDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "modifyUserId": 0,
      "regUserId": 0
    },
    "otherFields": {
      "formID": 10,
      "width": 0,
      "rank": 3,
      "isHidden": false,
      "engName": "Cost",
      "arbName": "Cost",
      "fieldType": "textbox",
      "dataType": "text",
      "dataLength": 0,
      "remarks": null,
      "isFilter": true,
      "isInList": true,
      "modifyDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "id": 4,
      "createdDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "updatedDate": "2023-01-30T00:00:00",
      "modifyUserId": 0,
      "regUserId": 0
    }
  }
]
```

As we can see from the above response i am getting the duplication of other field

Below is my model class

```
 public class FormControlsDto
    {
        public FormControls FormControls { get; set; }
        public OtherFields OtherFields { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the combination of two model class name formcontrols and otherfields

Below are the model classes for formcontrols table and otherfields

```
 public class FormControls : BaseEntity
    {
        public int FormId { get; set; }
        public string ControlName { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string? Icon { get; set; }
        public string ArbCaption { get; set; }
        public string? EngCaption { get; set; }
        public string? MaxLength { get; set; }
        public string? MinLength { get; set; }
        public string? MaxValue { get; set; }
        public string? MinValue { get; set; }
        public string? DataType { get; set; }
        public bool? IsHidden { get; set; }
        public string? DefaultValue { get; set; }
        public string? DefaultValueScalarFun { get; set; }
        public bool? Required { get; set; }
        public string? RegExpression { get; set; }
        public string ControlType { get; set; }
        public int? SearchId { get; set; }
        public string? AnotherCriteria { get; set; }
        public bool? Disabled { get; set; }
        public bool? IndexPage { get; set; }
        public int? Width { get; set; }
        public int? Section { get; set; }
        public bool? AutoGenerate { get; set; }
        public int? Rank { get; set; }
        public string? EngToolTip { get; set; }
        public string? ArbToolTip { get; set; }


    }
```

```
 public class OtherFields : BaseEntity
    {

        public int FormID { get; set; }

        public int? Width { get; set; }

        public int? Rank { get; set; }
        public bool IsHidden { get; set; }

        public string? EngName { get; set; }

        public string? ArbName { get; set; }

        public string? FieldType { get; set; }

        public string? DataType { get; set; }

        public short? DataLength { get; set; }

        public string? Remarks { get; set; }

        public bool  IsFilter { get; set; }
        public bool IsInList { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Please update your question with Model classes.

Comment: Update question with `FormControl` and  `OtherField` classes and their navigation properties.

Comment: there is no navigation property between the two tables bcoz one formID can have multiple formcontrols and multiple otherfields

Comment: Then you have wrong DTO it should have List of OtherFileds. `public List<OtherFields> OtherFields { get; set; }`. And please post classes.

Answer (score 0):

Change `FormControlsDto` to:

```cs
public class FormControlsDto
{
    public List<FormControls> FormControls { get; set; }
    public List<OtherFields> OtherFields { get; set; }
}
```

And then fill in the following query:

```cs
int formId = ...;

var dto = new FormControlsDto
    {
        FormControls = await _context.FormControls.Where(c => c.FormId == formId).ToListAsync(),
        OtherFields = await _context.OtherFields.Where(f => d.FormId == formId).ToListAsync()
    };
```

Comment: tried above solution but its returning same repeated otherfields object

Comment: You need all controls and all other fields for the form? Right?

Comment: Yes i need all the controls but i do not need repeated controls now in above case the otherfields are getting everytime i select formcontrols

Comment: Do you have input parameter `formId`?

Comment: Yes i have the formId